# 404 while using Spring cloud FeignClients

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

This is my setup:

First service(FlightIntegrationApplication) which invoke second service(BaggageServiceApplication) using FeignClients API and Eureka.

Project on github: https://github.com/IdanFridman/BootNetflixExample

First service:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan("com.bootnetflix")
public class FlightIntegrationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(FlightIntegrationApplication.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

in one of the controllers:

```
    @RequestMapping("/flights/baggage/list/{id}")
    public String getBaggageListByFlightId(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return flightIntegrationService.getBaggageListById(id);
    }
```

FlightIntegrationService:

```
    public String getBaggageListById(String id) {
        URI uri = registryService.getServiceUrl("baggage-service", "http://localhost:8081/baggage-service");
        String url = uri.toString() + "/baggage/list/" + id;
        LOG.info("GetBaggageList from URL: {}", url);

        ResponseEntity<String> resultStr = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
        LOG.info("GetProduct http-status: {}", resultStr.getStatusCode());
        LOG.info("GetProduct body: {}", resultStr.getBody());
        return resultStr.getBody();

    }
```

RegistryService:

```
@Named
public class RegistryService {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RegistryService.class);


    @Autowired
    LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;

    public URI getServiceUrl(String serviceId, String fallbackUri) {
        URI uri;
        try {
            ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose(serviceId);
            uri = instance.getUri();
            LOG.debug("Resolved serviceId '{}' to URL '{}'.", serviceId, uri);

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // Eureka not available, use fallback
            uri = URI.create(fallbackUri);
            LOG.error("Failed to resolve serviceId '{}'. Fallback to URL '{}'.", serviceId, uri);
        }

        return uri;
    }

}
```

And this is the second service (baggage-service):

BaggageServiceApplication:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.bootnetflix")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class BaggageServiceApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(BaggageServiceApplication.class).run(args);
    }

}
```

BaggageService:

```
@FeignClient("baggage-service")
public interface BaggageService {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/baggage/list/{flight_id}")
    List<String> getBaggageListByFlightId(@PathVariable("flight_id") String flightId);


}
```

BaggageServiceImpl:

```
@Named
public class BaggageServiceImpl implements BaggageService{

....

    @Override
    public List<String> getBaggageListByFlightId(String flightId) {
        return Arrays.asList("2,3,4");
    }

}
```

When invoking the rest controller of flight integration service I get:

```
2015-07-22 17:25:40.682  INFO 11308 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] c.b.f.service.FlightIntegrationService   : GetBaggageList from URL: http://X230-Ext_IdanF:62007/baggage/list/4
2015-07-22 17:25:43.953 ERROR 11308 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /flights/baggage/list/4

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
```

Any idea ?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks backwards to me.

The feign client for the baggage service should be declared in the flight service and the baggage service should have a controller that responds on the URL you map in your baggage service client, you should *not* implement the interface annotated with `@FeignClient`.

The setup you have now will not have any controller listening on */baggage/list/{flightId}* in the baggage service and no Feign client in flight service - the whole point of Feign is to call methods on an interface instead of manually handling URLs, Spring Cloud takes care of auto-instantiating the interface implementation and will use Eureka for discovery.

Try this (or modify so it fits your real world app):

**Flight Service:**

*FlightIntegrationService.java:*

```
@Component
public class FlightIntegrationService {

    @Autowired
    BaggageService baggageService;

    public String getBaggageListById(String id) {
        return baggageService.getBaggageListByFlightId(id);
    }
}
```

*BaggageService.java:*

```
@FeignClient("baggage-service")
public interface BaggageService {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/baggage/list/{flight_id}")
    List<String> getBaggageListByFlightId(@PathVariable("flight_id") String flightId);   
}
```

**Baggage Service:**

*BaggageController.java:*

```
@RestController
public class BaggageController {

    @RequestMapping("/baggage/list/{flightId}")
    public List<String> getBaggageListByFlightId(@PathVariable String flightId) {
        return Arrays.asList("2,3,4");
    }
}
```

Remove *BaggageService.java* and *BaggageServiceImpl.java* from the Baggage Service

Comment: Shouldn't the `BaggageController` implement the `BaggageService`?

Comment: Not necessarily - sometimes you want to get the request or response objects in the controller or handle multiple interface methods with the same controller method. A good example is query parameters where you can have default values for missing parameters in one controller method but need multiple interface methods if you want to avoid calling it with a bunch of `null`s.

Answer (score 1):

`registryService.getServiceUrl("baggage-service", ...` replace with

```
registryService.getServiceUrl("baggage-service")
```

make sure that matches the right name

remove the localhost part

or only use the http://local part

It only worked for us if you have just the name of the service listed in eureka dashboard, not both

Comment: I dont understand. you wrote the same line.

Comment: The localhost only mention in the faillback-url not in the main one